# Proving a Ring-Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My question is:

Show that 
    φ$\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
 T  &\mbox{$\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$}  \\
 \begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & 0\\ 
  b & c 
\end{pmatrix} & \mbox{$\longrightarrow$  $c$}
\end{array}\right.$

is a ring-homomorphism.

With T being $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & 0\\ 
  b & c 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

I get that the definition of a Homomorphism is when a ring satisfies

$f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$

and $f(ab) = f(a) f(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$

But cant seem to prove the original question. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping $\varphi$  associates to a lower triangular $2\times 2$-matrix its lower right coefficient.

Take two such matrices:
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&c\end{pmatrix},\quad T'=\begin{pmatrix}a'&0\\b'&c'\end{pmatrix},$$
compute $T+T'$, $TT'$ and check $\;\varphi(T+T')=\varphi(T)+\varphi
(T')$, $\;\varphi(TT')=\varphi(T)\varphi
(T')$.

Comment: when stating $\;\varphi(T+T')$, are you just saying $\begin{pmatrix}a+a'&0\\b+b'&c+c'\end{pmatrix}$??

Comment: Exactly. $\mbox{}$

Comment: If thats the case then why has the question used the function φ if it had no bearing in the addition of T and T'

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. By $\varphi(T+T')$, I mean $\varphi\begin{pmatrix}a+a'&0\\b+b'&c+c'\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense now. So for checking $\varphi(T+T')$ would you start by saying $\varphi(T+T')=\varphi(\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&c\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}a'&0\\b'&c'\end{pmatrix})$ which simplifies to $\begin{pmatrix}a+a'&0\\b+b'&c+c'\end{pmatrix}$ which can be rewritten as $\varphi(T) +\varphi(T')$

Comment: Not quite.  $\phi(T+T')=c+c'$ (lower right coefficient), and $\varphi (T)=c$, $\;\varphi (T')=c'$, so $\phi(T+T')=\varphi (T)+\varphi (T')$.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. So if the question was rewritten as φ$\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     T  &\mbox{$\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$}  \\
     \begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & 0\\ 
  b & c 
\end{pmatrix} & \mbox{$\longrightarrow$  $b$}
\end{array}\right.$, would this not be a ring-homomorphism??

Comment: It would not, as that map is not multiplicative. It is, however, an abelian group homomorphism.