# Ring-Isomorphism Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My question is:

Show that T/I is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Where T=$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & 0\\ 
  b & c 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

and I=$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
  a     & 0\\ 
  b & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

I know Isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism but cant seem to apply my knowledge to this question.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let define the following map: $$\varphi\colon\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}T&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&c\end{pmatrix}&\mapsto &c\end{array}\right..$$
Notice that $\varphi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism whose kernel is $I$. Using [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem), one has the desired ring isomorphism.

As a side note, when you are asked to prove an isomorphism between a quotient $X/Y$ and $Z$, it is a good idea to seak first surjective homomorphisms between $X$ and $Z$.

*Edit.* This idea is even more relevant when the above homomorphism was first introduce to you in [a problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008677/proving-a-ring-homomorphism).